# What exactly is the arguments param in the onListen method in the StreamHandler interface

Tags: java, android, flutter

Another day, another question about the `StreamHandler` interface!
How can I manipulate the `arguments` parameter in the `onListen` method that can be found in the `StreamHandler` interface for `EventChannels`?
The java docs don't say much about this: https://docs.flutter.io/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/EventChannel.StreamHandler.html
So let's say I've got an `EventChannel` called `eventChannel`:

```
EventChannel eventChannel = new EventChannel(registrar.messenger(), "ok");
```

I now set the `StreamHandler` like so:

```
eventChannel.setStreamHandler(new StreamHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onListen(Object o, EventSink eventSink) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(Object o) {

    }
});
```

How can I determine what the first argument of the `onListen` method will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments `Object` is the native representation of the optional `arguments` parameter passed to [`receiveBroadcastStream`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/EventChannel/receiveBroadcastStream.html).